# calculate base and height frustum

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume

I would like to find a way to calculate the height (h1) and base (r2) of the frustum knowing it has the same volume than the underlying cone and the angles are the same.

I got to a 3rd degree unsolvable polynomial and I'm stuck. Any help is welcome.

Thank you

[image: Frustum]

Comment: What did you do to get that degree 3 polynomial, i.e. show steps please... Also what was the polynomial.

Comment: I had r2 = r+r3 (r3 being the extra part of the large radius of the frustum).
Then V = pi/3 * h * ((r+r3)^2 + (r+r3)*r + r^2)
and also h = tan(alpha)*r3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we note that, since we have the small gray cone, which is part of the larger cone formed when appending the frustrum, we have that
$$ \frac{h+h_1}{r_2} = \frac{h}{r} = 5$$
Next, we relate the volumes as follows:
\begin{align}
V_{\text{little cone}} &= V_{\text{frustrum}} \\
&= V_{\text{big cone}} - V_{\text{little cone}} \\
2V_{\text{little cone}} &= V_{\text{big cone}} \\
2\cdot \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h &= \frac{1}{3}\pi r_2^2(h+h_1) \\
2r^2 h &= r_2^2(h+h_1) \\
2r^2 (5r) &= r_2^2(5r_2) \\
2r^3 &= r_2^3 \\
r_2 &= \sqrt[3]{2} r \\
&= \sqrt[3]{2} (100 \text{ m}) \\
&\approx 125.992 \text{ m}
\end{align}
From the first equation, we have
\begin{align}
h_1 &= 5r_2 - h \\
&= 5(100\sqrt[3]{2} \text{ m}) - 500 \text{ m} \\
&= 500(\sqrt[3]{2}-1) \text{ m} \\
&\approx 129.960 \text{ m}
\end{align}

Comment: cool, I didn't see it this way! thanks